# the set of all of infinite N subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was thinking about this one for a while and can't find a proper function.

let $M=${$A\in P(N)$|A And A' are infinite}

(for example: the set of all **even numbers** will be in M, the complement of A will be all **odd numbers** (of N). )

I need to find the cardinal number of M.

so I know that $M\subseteq P(N)\rightarrow|M|\leq|P(N)=C$

now for the other way, what one to one function can I show to M?

Comment: Maybe don't find explicit one. Show instead that the collection of sets **not** in $M$ is countable.

Answer (score 2):

For each subset $A \subseteq P(\Bbb N)$, define $B$ by taking three times each element of $A$, union the set of naturals $\equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Both $B$ and $B'$ are infinite, so we have an injection of $A$ into $M$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\setminus M$ is the union of two countable sets.